# Nividea Geforce 820m grafics card only displaying black screens

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

Please help me. For a few weeks I've a a really bad problem. My Geforce 820m graphics card shows Unity and other programs as only a blank screen, crashes my programs and even sometimes stops my display driver from working these things happen depending on what driver I am using. When I run these programs with integrated graphics they seem to work.

I'm not sure if the problem is to do with drivers or hardware. I started to get the problem around the time I upgraded my lenovo Z50 laptop from four GBs of RAM to 16gbs. But it also happened around the time I updated my graphics driver.

I've tried so many different drivers:

I tried the driver my computer supposedly shipped with(I found it here"http://support.lenovo.com/au/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-z-series-laptops/lenovo-z50-70?tabName=Downloads&beta=false") but it seems to old to have come with my computer since I only bought it last year it is from 2014. It caused all of my programs to crash when I opened them with Nivdia graphics.

I also tried most of the drivers on Nivdia's site some which I cant remember. Some caused my computer to go black and say Display driver stopped responding and recovered. While other and most like the "361.43" driver just caused my programs to look like this.

Even though all of the drivers haven't worked in full they all still show the spinning Nivdia symbol in the Nivdia control panel which means they are working a bit.

Is there something Physically wrong with my graphics card? if not what drivers or other software should I try/change? Please comment any additional information you need me to give you.

Thanks any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Who ever posted an answer to my question previously(Which for some reason has been deleted" was correct. The issue was with windows. Either installing the ram or jumping between drivers really upset windows 8.1. I didn't even need to do full reset. I just use the refresh your pc function of windows. It deleted lots of stuff and reinstalled the OS but it left me all of my Photos and other similar things on the hard drive. Thank you who ever it was. :)

Any one with this problem after trying every thing should reinstall their OS. 
REMEMBER TO MAKE A BACK UP OF ALL IMPORTANT FILES IN CASE SOMETHING GOES WRONG.